# TSQL - aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate ERROR

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

Hi there I have a procedure like so:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DWS_PROG (
                                @fromDate datetime = '2012-01-01',
                                @maxMoney money = 200,
                                @limit int = 200 
                              )
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON; 

SELECT TOP (@limit)
     convert(int,P.P_ID) AS 'ID'
    , max(convert(MONEY,isnull(P.NGp,P.NGz))) AS 'NG'
    , max(convert(MONEY,(CASE WHEN D.Doc_Type = 0x0000000000000016 
                              THEN Cash_PLN 
                              ELSE 0 END))) AS 'Interests'
    , (SELECT TOP 1 convert(VARCHAR, H.Data_zmiany,105) 
         FROM dbo.Pozew_Historia_Stanow H 
        WHERE  H.P_ID = P.P_ID 
          AND H.Stan_nastepny_id = 0x000000000000000D /*PZ*/) AS 'Data Pozwu'
    , max((CASE WHEN Sad_Id=0x0000000000000E08 
                THEN 'EL' 
                ELSE 'PA' END)) AS 'TYPE'
    , max((CASE WHEN Cost_Name =0x0000000000000008 
                THEN convert(varchar, Pay_Date,105) 
                ELSE NULL END)) AS 'Data pierwszego kosztu wpisu sądowego'
    , (SELECT TOP 1 convert(VARCHAR, H.Data_zmiany,105) 
         FROM dbo.Pozew_Historia_Stanow H 
        WHERE H.P_ID = P.P_ID 
          AND H.Stan_nastepny_id = 0x00000000000000DD /*EGZ-1*/) AS 'Data wszczęcia egzekucji'
    , sum((CASE WHEN D.Doc_Type = 0x0000000000000003 
                 AND D.Pay_Date >= @fromDate 
                 AND D.Pay_Date < DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,@fromDate) + 1,0) 
                THEN Cash_PLN 
                ELSE 0 END)) AS 'M0'
 FROM dbo.Pozew P 
 JOIN dbo.Orders  Z 
   ON Z.Orders_Id = P.Orders_Id 
 JOIN dbo.Docs D 
   ON D.P_ID = P.P_ID
WHERE ((P.NGp IS NOT NULL AND P.NGp < @maxMoney) OR (P.NGp IS NULL AND P.NGz < @maxMoney))
  AND P.Stan IN ('PZ-PORAŻKA','PZ-PORAŻ-UB','PZ-PSPPOR-SP','PZ-PSPPOR-UP','PZ-PSSSUK-UP','PZ-ZAPŁATA','EGZ-C-ROSZ-1','EGZ-C-ROSZ-2','EGZ-SUKCES-S','EGZ-ZAS-R','EGZ-NZAS-R','EGZ-BS-1C','EGZ-WSZP-1','EGZ-WSZP-2','EGZ-SPL')
  AND (SELECT TOP 1 dbo.Docs.Pay_Date 
         FROM dbo.Docs 
        WHERE dbo.Docs.P_ID = P.P_ID 
          AND dbo.Docs.Cost_Name = 0x0000000000000008 
     ORDER BY dbo.Docs.Pay_Date) >= @fromDate
GROUP BY P.P_ID
```

This basicly works fine, but I have one error.
In the last line before JOIN I sum cash for all Documents that have type 0x00...03 and Pay_date is between @param and end of month for param. Simple and works :)

But I must replace @fromDate with subquery:

```
SELECT TOP 1 dbo.Docs.Pay_Date 
  FROM dbo.Docs 
 WHERE dbo.Docs.P_ID = P.P_ID 
   AND dbo.Docs.Cost_Name = 0x0000000000000008 
   AND dbo.Docs.Pay_Date >= @fromDate  
 ORDER BY dbo.Docs.Pay_Date
```

So that for every document query will take the first date with specific type of payment and then it will sum all payments starting from this date to end of month.

SUM should look like this:

```
SUM((CASE WHEN D.Doc_Type = 0x0000000000000003 
           AND D.Pay_Date >= 
               (SELECT TOP 1 dbo.Docs.Pay_Date 
                  FROM dbo.Docs 
                 WHERE dbo.Docs.P_ID = P.P_ID 
                   AND dbo.Docs.Cost_Name = 0x0000000000000008 
                   AND dbo.Docs.Pay_Date >= @fromDate  
                 ORDER BY dbo.Docs.Pay_Date)

           AND D.Pay_Date < DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, 
              (SELECT TOP 1 dbo.Docs.Pay_Date 
                 FROM dbo.Docs 
                WHERE dbo.Docs.P_ID = P.P_ID 
                  AND dbo.Docs.Cost_Name = 0x0000000000000008 
                  AND dbo.Docs.Pay_Date >= @fromDate 
                ORDER BY dbo.Docs.Pay_Date)) + 1,0) 
         THEN Cash_PLN 
         ELSE 0 END)) AS 'M0'
```

But after doing that Management Studio throws an error:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

I'm trying to solve that for almost 2 days.
Any ideas?

Sorry for not showing structure of tables, but the database is too big and I only need a way to solve that error :)

My tables look like so:
Table Pozew: id, name, etc

Table Docs: docid, p_id (key from Pozew table), doc_type, cost_name, pay_date, cash_PLN

And sample records look like so:

Docs:

1,1,15,8,'2011-02-04',400
1,1, 3,5,'2011-02-09',0
1,1, 3,5,'2011-02-12',0
1,1, 3,5,'2011-02-04',0

Simple scenario:
we add a record to docs table saying we have 1th document with cost_name=0x8, then other documents are added but with Doc_Type = 0x3.

So we want to get all documents that have doc_Type =0x3 and were added between creation date of first document with cost_name=0x8 and end of month.
But we must group them for every Pozew_id.

Sorry for my pour english :/

I have created a simple query that will show my problem more clearly:

```
DECLARE @fromDate varchar
SET @fromDate = '2011-06-01'
SELECT TOP 100
sum((CASE WHEN D.Typ_dokumentu = 0x0000000000000003 
          AND D.Data_platnosci >= 
          (SELECT TOP 1 Data_platnosci
           FROM Dokumenty
           WHERE Pozew_Id = P.Pozew_Id 
           AND Nazwa_kosztu = 0x0000000000000008
           AND Data_platnosci >= @fromDate 
           GROUP BY Pozew_Id) 
          AND Data_platnosci < DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,
          (SELECT TOP 1 Data_platnosci 
           FROM Dokumenty 
           WHERE Pozew_Id = P.Pozew_Id
           AND Nazwa_kosztu = 0x0000000000000008
           AND Data_platnosci >= @fromDate
           GROUP BY Pozew_Id)
           ) + 1,0) THEN Kwota_PLN ELSE 0 END)) AS 'M0'
FROM
Dokumenty D
JOIN Pozew P
    ON D.Pozew_Id = P.Pozew_Id
WHERE
((P.NGp IS NOT NULL
AND
P.NGp < 200)
OR
(P.NGp IS NULL
AND
P.NGz < 200))
AND
P.Stan IN ('PZ-PORAŻKA','PZ-PORAŻ-UB','PZ-PSPPOR-SP')
AND
(SELECT TOP 1
     dbo.Dokumenty.Data_platnosci
 FROM
     dbo.Dokumenty
 WHERE
     dbo.Dokumenty.Pozew_Id = P.Pozew_Id
     AND
     dbo.Dokumenty.Nazwa_kosztu = 0x0000000000000008
 ORDER BY
     dbo.Dokumenty.Data_platnosci) >= @fromDate
```

Comment: Sorry @Filip De Vos for mess with formatting :/

Comment: No worries. on a gg=G in vim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it be possible to have a derived table in your join to provide the "first after @fromDate per type of payment" and then in your select statement to compare against that.

ie derived query something like

```
select p_id, min(pay_date) startDate  
from docs 
where cost_name = 0x0000000000000008 
  and pay_date >= @fromDate 
group by p_id 
order by pay_date
```

You join to the derived table by type of payment thus getting the appropriate starting date.

Then your sum is:

```
sum((case when d.doc_type = 0x0000000000000003 
           and d.pay_date >= startDate 
           and month(d.pay_date) = month(startDate) 
           and year(d.pay_date) = year(startDate)) then cash_pln 
          else 0 end) as 'M0'
```

Note I haven't tried this so it may not be completely correct but hopefully it shows the principle

Comment: I've done another join with table containing record from Your query. It works like a charm :)

Comment: Pseudo-SQL is the way forward! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would put the pay_date into a variable and work with that. It is a constant value after all.

```
DECLARE @pay_date datetime
SET @pay_date = (SELECT TOP 1 dbo.Docs.Pay_Date 
                   FROM dbo.Docs 
                  WHERE dbo.Docs.P_ID = P.P_ID 
                    AND dbo.Docs.Cost_Name = 0x0000000000000008 
                    AND dbo.Docs.Pay_Date >= @fromDate  
                  ORDER BY dbo.Docs.Pay_Date)
```

Then in your query

```
  AND D.Pay_Date >= @pay_date
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but (sorry if this sound silly) if I declare a variable and use it as above I will have all my records with pay_date bigger than @pay_date. What I need to do is to select pay_date for every document. I'll edit my post to show what kind of logic I want to accomplish :)